# Command button does not submit on "enter" press only in IE < 9

Tags: java, forms, internet-explorer, jsf, jsf-2

I have 2 `<h:form>` elements following each other (not one within the other) such as :

```
<h:form id="innerHeaderForm1">
    <h:inputText value="#{searchBar.eventname}" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{searchBar.search1}" value="click1"/>
</h:form>
<h:form id="innerHeaderForm2">
    <h:inputText id="last" value="#{searchBar.personname}"/>
    <h:commandButton action="#{searchBar.search2}" value="click2"/> 
</h:form>
```

This works fine.  The problem I have is that in IE 8 (and I'm assuming other older versions) when in the first form and I hit the "enter" key on my keybord, the form is not submitted.  The page reloads, but does not even call `#{searchBar.search1}`.

The odd thing in all this is that this works fine in the second form.  I don't get an error message nor do I get any feedback from the browser.

In my backing bean I have something of the sort :

```
public String search1() {
    System.out.println("submitting form1");
    return "success";
}

public String search2() {
    System.out.println("submitting form2");
    return "success";
}
```

When using hitting the "enter" key, I don't even make it to the backing bean.

But : when I do "click" the submit button (with the mouse) everything works.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a MSIE specific anomaly in case of forms with only one `<input type="text">` field. The only fix is to add another `<input type="text">` field which is hidden by CSS `display: none;`.

```html
<h:form id="innerHeaderForm1">
    <h:inputText value="#{searchBar.eventname}" />
    <h:inputText style="display: none;" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{searchBar.search1}" value="click1"/>
</h:form>
```

This problem is not related to JSF.

Comment: I tried searching the internet for this and couldn't find anything.  Is this documented somewhere?  This adds to my dislike of IE.  Thanks for the answer.  I would have scratched my head a long time before I would have chanced on this fix.

Comment: I can't find authoritative resources from Microsoft, but this MSIE specific anomaly already exist for ages and is known among the more experienced web developers. You can at least see in Google that you're not the only one: http://www.google.com/search?q=msie+single+text+input+submit+enter

Answer (score -2):

The `inputText` did not receive an `id="eventName"`.

Comment: This makes no sense. JSF autogenerates one anyway.