# JSF h:commandButton submit on Enter keypress not working

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have a simple form with an inputText and a commandButton. Normally if I use `onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) this.submit();"` I can submit the form pressing the Enter key. In the context of my application though this does not work. When I press the Enter key, the inputText is cleared but the form is not submitted and the action of the commandButton is not called. I'm using Icefaces and I'm seeing some `ice.captureEnterKey` in my page's source code but I don't know if that's relevant.

Page Code:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.query}"/>
    <h:commandButton id="search" value="Search" action="#{myBean.submitQuery()}" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) this.submit();"/>
</h:form>
```

UPDATE:
I've managed to make it work like this:

```
`<h:form id="form1">
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.query}" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('form1:search').click();"/>
    <h:commandButton id="search" value="Search" action="#{myBean.submitQuery()}"/>
</h:form>`
```

The problem now is that I get this weird error before I get navigated to the next page:

`Network connection interrupted. Reload this page to try to reconnect.`

The error only appears when I submit the form by pressing Enter. If I press the button with the mouse it does not appear. Also if I remove Icefaces libraries everything works fine.

Comment: Provide some relevant code. Also there are many questions on this on stackoverflow, did you look at them?

Comment: @Ravi As I said its just a simple form but see above for the code. I did see other questions and I don't think they solve this problem.

Comment: This one should solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235488/command-button-does-not-submit-on-enter-press-only-in-ie-9

Comment: Based in the code you've posted, the `onkeypress` code should be in your `<h:inputText>`, not in your `<h:commandButton>`, and try to add `type="submit"` tag attribute to your commandButton.

Comment: It`s a different if you submit the form or if you call the action method?? The first code submits only the form. The action on your managed bean would not be called, I think.. The second cold triggers a click on the Command Button who realy calls the action.. So.. Submitting the form is not the same as calling the action on the CommandButton or am I wrong?